# Preserve order of workspaces in PopOS/Gnome/Wayland when disconnecting/reconnecting to a second monitor

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, multi-monitor, wayland, pop-os

I have a laptop with Pop OS using Cosmic DE (Gnome version from 22.04) on top of Wayland.

Usually when at home I connect my laptop to another monitor to have a dual-setup monitor, but sometimes I work on my laptop on the go or just watch a movie from the bed.

Unfortunately when I disconnect and reconnect my laptop to the second monitor I never get a predictable order for my workspaces/applications.

[image]

As in the above image, it would be great if on **disconnecting** the second monitor:

- all apps in workspace 1 on the laptop display will go to workspace 1 in the only-laptop setup
- all apps in workspace 1 on the second monitor will go to workspace 2 in the only-laptop setup
- all apps in workspace 2 on the laptop display will go to workspace 3 in the only-laptop setup
- all apps in workspace 2 on the second monitor will go to workspace 4 in the only-laptop setup
- etc (if more workspaces)

On **reconnecting** the second monitor:

- all apps in workspace 1 will go to workspace 1 in the laptop display
- all apps in workspace 2 will go to workspace 1 in the second monitor
- all apps in workspace 3 will go to workspace 2 in the laptop display
- all apps in workspace 4 will go to workspace 2 in the second monitor
- etc (if more workspaces)

In case a display doesn't have any apps I am fine with it being skipped when assigning apps to a workspace as very rarely I have a display open with no apps.